# BCG Virtual Grid how to display from a specific row

Tags: c++, mfc, bcg

I have a `CBCGPGridCtrl` with virtual rows enabled (`EnableVirtualMode`).
No problem with data display.
On some event (right click from another window) I want to move the current visible part of the grid to a specific row.
I couldn't find any specific method to do that.
I tried a couple of different options:

1.
I saw that manually moving the scrollbar cause a change in the values of variable like: `m_nFirstVisibleItem`, `m_nLastVisibleItem` and `m_nVertScrollOffset`, so I thought to replicate that using `setScrollPos`.

```cpp
m_grid.SetScrollRange(SB_VERT, 0, size());
//....
m_grid.SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, gotoPosition);
```

But nothing happened and those variables were not affected.

2. The other idea I tried was to select the row I was interested in, with:

```cpp
m_grid.SetCurSel(gotoPosition);
```

None of those worked.

What is the right way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of different attempts, the only solution I was able to get to work is to have a child of `CBCGPGridCtrl` and intervene explicitly on the value of `m_nVertScrollOffset`.

So, it was something like this:

```cpp
class CChildGrid : public CBCGPGridCtrl
{
public:
    void SetScrollPos(int gotoPosition)
    {
        m_nVertScrollOffset = gotoPosition * m_nRowHeight;
    }
};
....
void CFoo::SetGridPosition()
{
   m_grid.SetScrollPos(125);
   m_grid.AdjustLayout();
}
```